# Web Part "Hidden" option is greyed out on team site wiki pages

Tags: web-part, wiki, hidden

For all the Web Parts on my SP 2010 team site wiki page, the "Hidden" option is greyed out (under Edit Web Part > Layout).

How can I activate this option?

Comment: I changed **IsVisible** property by exporting the webpart file. I set it **false** from **true**.
But it does not show the web part even in edit mode.

Comment: I just checked with an HTML Form WebPart and it worked. The WebPart imported properly and is invisible. To see if the WebPart is there open the page in maintenance mode by appending ?Contents=1 to the page url.

Comment: I forgot to mention: yes it is invisible, even in edit mode of the page. I guess that's the reason why Microsoft has disabled this feature in the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue a while ago. As a temporary workaround I exported the WebPart into a DWP file and edited it with a text editor (I prefer Notepad++). Once done I imported it back and added it to the page.

Comment: What edit did you do? Change to the IsVisible property, like Prachi?

Comment: Yes, toggle the IsVisible to show/hide a WebPart. If you are in doubt create a new Document Library and select "Web Part Page" as document template. Then create a new WebPart page and add the e.g. HTML Form WebPart and modify the properties to hide it. Then export it and import it where you want to have it.